# How to import data from SQL to a data.table format?

Tags: r, data.table

I have recently learnt how faster is to create and work with data in data.table format.

My question is if there is a way to import directly from the SQL server to a data.table (I imagine it should be a lot faster). I currently use the sqlQuery function from the RODBC package, which imports data to data.frame format and it takes a lot of time for big datasets.

Comment: dump data to csv and read that, db drivers you can get for free won't be efficient, especially from microsoft

Comment: hi, which version of SQL server are you using? you might be able to run the R code directly inside the SQL server

Comment: Since you mentioned *"big datasets"*, I've adapted my SQL-accessing code to use *bulk operations* when able. For SQL Server, for instance, one can use `bcp` and/or `sqlcmd`, and while they both have egregious shortcomings, some of them can be overcome, and the speed-savings using them vice standard `DBI`- or `RODBC`-based functions can be considerable. Other DBMSs have similar commands. They are external to R (and typically work over ODBC), so you would require either `system` or `processx::run` to run them.

Comment: From there, though, you're back to basic R questions: how to read in data from a CSV (`read.csv`, `readr::read_csv`, `vroom::vroom`, or the fastest, `data.table::fread`). I know of no database connection object that natively returns `data.table`; in R, they typically all return a `data.frame`, on which you simply call `as.data.table` or `setDT`. So your question really has nothing to do with `data.table` and all about SQL speed of download.

Comment: (BTW: there is a little bit of overhead in using `bcp`/`sqlcmd`, namely in the `system` calling, management, and such. For smaller datasets, it's often more efficient to use the direct `RODBC::sqlQuery` or `DBI::dbGetQuery`. The balance point for where `bcp` becomes faster is dependent on several factors, not something we can easily answer here with a lot more information.)

Comment: @chinsoon12 I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v11.0.5434.0

Comment: Hi I am referring to the server not the IDE